# Play last few seconds of mp3

Tags: bash, audio, mp3, sox

Is there any way to play last N seconds of an `mp3` file on `bash` commandline?

Comment: Do you know how long it is to start with and its sample rate? mpg123 -k $FOO skips $FOO number of frames. At that point it's just arithmetic to figure out...

Comment: @Bandrami, figured out, check answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667081/how-do-you-trim-the-audio-files-end-using-sox

Solution:

```
play nameOfMp3 reverse trim 0 N reverse
```

(where `N` is the number of seconds).

Comment: On Debian-based systems, you may need to install `libsox-fmt-mp3` first.